# Android:How to show the location source settings programmatically?

Tags: android, setting

I want to open location source settings,I do as this

```
    Intent intent = new Intent( Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS );
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

but in some phones(main Android 4.0.4,some 4.1.2) it report an exception:

```
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent {   act=android.settings.LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS }
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1518)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1390)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromChild(Activity.java:3472)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3224)
at cn.safetrip.edog.function.map.h.onClick(HomeActivity.java:970)
at     com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:169)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have no idea...

Comment: check this ans: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15918245/1168654

Answer (score 8):

Try this one:

```
 startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 0);
```

and What is the activity name you have put the code.

Comment: How is this different from the original question?

Comment: I don't remember , may be he edited the question like 2 years ago...Developers in stack overflow never give 2 points for stupid answers.